# How to give custom domain name inside Azure Openshift cluster 4.4

Tags: azure, dns, openshift, aro

I have an Openshift cluster created inside Azure cloud provider.

I have created some pods and exposed some of them to outside the cluster using **Routes**.

The route generally comes with some default canonical name something like below

"http://vote-voting-application.apps.xxxxxx.southeastasia.aroapp.io" .

Lets assume I have a domain name called avenir.com , How can I configure my openshift cluster to use this domain name avenir.com to use instead of "apps.xxxxxx.southeastasia.aroapp.io".

Please help in achieving this .

Any type of help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift Routes will default to an auto-generated hostname but that can be overridden by setting `.spec.hostname`

For example:

```
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  host: avenir.com
...
```

OpenShift uses something.apps.cluster-name.domain by default because it sets up wildcard DNS to return the IP of the ingress VIP.

**NOTE:** You are responsible for setting up DNS to direct traffic for avenir.com to your ingress VIP. You could simply make the DNS record for avenir.com a CNAME to something.apps.cluster-name.domain (or in your example something.apps.xxxxxx.southeastasia.aroapp.io)

Comment: can you please comment on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65137145/network-policy-in-kubernetes-not-working-in-different-namespaces